# Using Combobox to Filter ListBox in a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am trying to filter data from a worksheet (Name: "Input", Range: B2:J to last row) onto a list box (Name: lstbox1) and apply a filter to the list box by selecting an option from a combobox drop down (cmbFilter) that equals values in Column J of "Input" worksheet.

I am very new to VBA, and I have no idea how to amend this so that it successfully shows only filtered rows in the listbox. Please, I would really appreciate any help with this.

```
Private Sub cmbFilter_Change()

Dim sh As Worksheet Dim lr As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input") lr = Sheets("Input").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lr = 1 Then lr = 2

With Me.ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 9
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnWidths = "30,40,150,60,60,180,50,0,80"
    .RowSource = "Input!B2:J" & lr

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
Private Sub cmbFilter_Change()
    Dim col, i

    col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("1:1"))
    ListBox1.ColumnCount = col + 1
    ListBox1.Clear
    
    With Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(2, ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1), 
         Sheet1.Cells(10000, ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1))
   
    
         Set Sr = .Find(cmbFilter.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    
         If Not Sr Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress= Sr.Address
        
            Do
              ListBox1.AddItem " "
              For i = 0 To col
                  ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, i + 1) = Sheet1.Cells(Sr.Row, i + 1)
              Next i
                                 
                                 
              Set Sr = .FindNext(Sr)
            Loop While Not Sr Is Nothing And Sr.Address <> firstAddress
         End If
    End With
End Sub
```